# What is the difference between Fullmetal Alchemist and Fullmetal Alchemist: Brotherhood?

Tags: anime, fullmetal-alchemist

I have read on Wikipedia that:

> Fullmetal Alchemist: Brotherhood is the second anime television series based on Fullmetal Alchemist, the first being 2003's Fullmetal Alchemist, and unlike its predecessor it directly follows the events of the manga.

Fullmetal Alchemist and Fullmetal Alchemist: Brotherhood are they telling the same story or they are different?

Comment: You answered it yourself -- Brotherhood is based on the manga, whereas the first one had a different story.

Comment: We have some answers [here](http://anime.stackexchange.com/q/55/49) at Anime & Manga.

Comment: That's a bizarre choice for "duplicate"...

Comment: The duplicate is on the Anime Stack Exchange which does not allow duplicates from this Stack. [FMA vs FMAB](http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/55/whats-the-difference-between-the-fma-and-fma-brotherhood-series).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The original FMA was produced while the manga was incomplete. This meant they focused more on the early parts of the story, and when they ran out, they inserted their own plotline.

FMAB was produced after the manga was close to completion. There they rushed through the parts adapted in the original, and then provided a faithful adaptation of the full story.

Comment: I should add that - unlike other famous series which had to somehow improvise an ending after they ran out of written material and did, ahem, questionable work (Game of Thrones comes to mind) - the ending of the first FMA series is pretty solid in my opinion.